# Dynamically adding new objects to UITableViewcell on cell selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using UITableView to display a list of scores for each team in one row. I would like it so that when the user selects any particular cell(team) to see the score, the height of the cell becomes double and hence the scores of the selected team becomes visible. I am able to adjust the row height on selection & deselection but unable to add labels dynamically for listing the scores. Please suggest some solution for this scenario. How can we dynamically add objects(labels) to uitableviewcell on didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_balls count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"cell for row at index path");
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CommentaryTableCell *tableCell = (CommentaryTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (tableCell == nil) {
        tableCell = [[CommentaryTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    /*
    if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0)
        tableCell.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"EAEAEA"];
    else
        tableCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    */
    NSString *over = [_balls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSArray *overData = [_ballsPerOver objectForKey:over];
    NSString *ball1 = [overData objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *ball2 = [overData objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *ball3 = [overData objectAtIndex:2];
    NSString *ball4 = [overData objectAtIndex:3];
    NSString *ball5 = [overData objectAtIndex:4];
    NSString *ball6 = [overData objectAtIndex:5];
    tableCell.overLabel.text = over;
    tableCell.ball1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:ball1];
    tableCell.ball2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:ball2];
    tableCell.ball3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:ball3];
    tableCell.ball4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:ball4];
    tableCell.ball5.image = [UIImage imageNamed:ball5];
    tableCell.ball6.image = [UIImage imageNamed:ball6];

    tableCell.teamLabel.text  = @"IND";
    tableCell.ball1Label.text = ball1;
    tableCell.ball2Label.text = ball2;
    tableCell.ball3Label.text = ball3;

    tableCell.videoThumbnail.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"th1.jpg"];
    return tableCell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    int rowHeight;

    if ([indexPath row] == self.currentSelection)
    {
        rowHeight = self.newCellHeight;
    }
    else
    {
        rowHeight = 44.0f;
    }
    return rowHeight;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // do things with your cell here

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CommentaryTableCell *tableCell = (CommentaryTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // set selection
    self.currentSelection = indexPath.row;

    // save height for full text label
    if(!self.cellSelected)
    {
        NSLog(@"when selected");
        self.newCellHeight = (tableCell.frame.size.height) * 6;
        self.cellSelected = true;
        self.cellloadedOnce = true;
        tableCell.videoThumbnail.hidden = false;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"when de selected");
        self.newCellHeight = 44;
        self.cellSelected = false;
        self.cellloadedOnce = false;
    }

    // animate
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // do things with your cell here

    NSLog(@"when De selected at row index");
    // sentinel
    self.currentSelection = -1;

    // animate
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: What about having those score labels in cell always and only changing their visibility in `didSelect` / `didDeselect` methods?

Comment: @JakubVano I have already tried that approach... it is not working.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like an accordion view?

Comment: @NSDumb Yes a kind of accordion view with the contents in a row which show/hide when a row expand/collapse respectively

Comment: If that's the case then have a look at this : https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=accordion @sonal third party controls have to reviewed as per your requirements and then needs to be integrated with the application

Comment: @NSDumb.. I am able to implement show/hide of the row but the content which are supposed to be shown at row expansion is not visible.

Comment: @sonal: maybe they are not initialized correct can you apply a break point and check

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good solution to display it on the same UITableViewCell. I suggest to use another conception and display all scores in another UITableView by using navigation push..

If you really want to do this, you can always display scores for all UITableViewCell and just adjust the height of the cell when you click ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Well I have already tried to implement the second option given by you at first place...but it is not working fine...all scores are overlapping on the cell next to which it is associated...

Comment: and the second one ? you can construct your cell by adding all the score for the current team and just changing height when the user click.. ?

Comment: @djoosi...that is what I am doing...I have already added the score labels to the cell beneath the team name & have restricted the size such the only team name is visible. Now on clicking the cell ...height of my cell increase but scores are not visible.

Comment: @djoosi..I have posted code for your reference...I have created these label in cell and have also made IBOutlets for the same